# Using "Libertine Display" as the main font in a beamer document

Tags: beamer, fonts, libertine

In a `beamer` document with the `serif` font scheme, I would like to use the "Libertine Display" font as a lighter alternative to the standard "Libertine Regular" (see http://www.linuxlibertine.org/index.php?id=86&L=1 --> Styles).

But the `\libertineDisplay` command from the `libertine` package does have no effect. The embedded font, as reported in the document properties of my viewer, is the same whether `\libertineDisplay` is enabled or not.

This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usefonttheme{serif}

\usepackage{libertine}
\libertineDisplay %doesn't change anything

\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Introduction}
\kant[1]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `libertine` package has no provision for making Linux Libertine Display the main text font.

The command `\libertineDisplay` is a font switch, similar to `\sffamily`.

You can make “Display” the main font with a hack:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usefonttheme{serif}

\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\libertine@family{Libertine}{LibertineDisplay}{}{}
\makeatother

\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Introduction}

\kant[1]

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Be warned that the font is only available in upright shape: no italic and no boldface.

If you just want to change the font for medium weight and normal shape, you can copy the file

```
OT1LinuxLibertineT-TLF.fd
```

in the working directory and change

```
 66 \DeclareFontShape{OT1}{LinuxLibertineT-TLF}{m}{n}{
 67       <-> \LinuxLibertineT@@scale LinLibertineT-tlf-ot1
 68 }{}
```

into

```
 66 \DeclareFontShape{OT1}{LinuxLibertineT-TLF}{m}{n}{
 67       <-> \LinuxLibertineT@@scale LinLibertineDisplayT-tlf-ot1
 68 }{}
```

(line numbers just for reference; 2017/03/20 release).

You can use a different strategy if you use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX and `fontspec`

```
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{LinLibertine_}[
  Extension=.otf,
  UprightFont=*DR,
  ItalicFont=*RI,
  BoldFont=*RB,
  BoldItalicFont=*RBI,
  % other features
]
```

Comment: Thank you. But "Libertine Regular" isn't bold/italic/typewriter etc. too. Those shapes are separate fonts, activated by the corresponding font switch commands. I just want to substitute the regular roman for main text with "Libertine Display". Does your hack achieve this?

Comment: @AlexG No, it doesn't. I don't think you really want it. Are you using regular `pdflatex` or XeLaTeX?

Comment: Currently `pdflatex`.

Comment: @AlexG You should make a copy of `OT1LinuxLibertineT-TLF.fd` in your working directory and change the entry for `{m}{n}` to have `LinLibertineDisplayT` instead of `LinLibertineT`.

Comment: This works very well! Thanks! I just wonder why we couldn't place the command in question, `\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{LinuxLibertineT-TLF}{m}{n}{..}`, directly into the header of the document source file?

Comment: @AlexG You can do it, but you have to put all the file contents.

Comment: Ok, that's too much. Copying and modifying the file would be the option I'd pick. Would you please add this to your answer?

Comment: Thanks also for the `fontspec` way, @egreg!